# dojox.form.Uploader and FileList - FileList does not show multiple files

Tags: dojo

I have a problem with dojox.form.Uploader. I want to use it to attach files for sending an e-mail and although I think I have pretty much copied the examples of the documentation I have not succeeded in making it work along with the FileList for seeing what has been attached.

In detail I have created this ContentPane:

```
attachPane = new ContentPane({
    id: name + "attach_top" + counter,
    region: 'right',
    style: "width: 55%; height: 100%;",
    "class": "edgePanel",
    content: "<div id='attachdiv'></div>" +
             "<div id='files' dojoType='dojox.form.uploader.FileList' uploaderId='uploader'></div>" +
             "<input type='button' id='remBtn' label='Clear' dojoType='dijit.form.Button' />"
});
```

which is inside a BorderContainer. This ContentPane is created after clicking on a button. With this click I also create with a function the Uploader and bind it with the  like so:

```
function createattacher(name) {                
        var attacher = new dojox.form.Uploader({
        id: "uploader",
        label: "Add Attachments",
        multiple: true,                    
        url: "./Attachments.apsx"
    }, "attachdiv");
    attacher.startup();                
}
```

The Uploader is working I can select files BUT the FileList widget ONLY shows one file at a time!!!! When I try to Upload another file the new one is not added to the FileList but it replaces the previous, making it look like if only one file has been uploaded. Eventhough the Uploader as you can see has the attribute "multiple: true"!!

What am I doing wrong? I lost half of my day for this silly thing :(
I bet it must be obvious but I am stuck! Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select multiple files at the same time in the select window